# Android xml : last lines hidden by relative layout footer

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing a layout for my android app. There is a header and a footer fixed. I put a scrollview between them, all works fine except that The last line of the content is hidden by the footer and I don't know how fix it!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#EEEEEE">
<!-- HEADER -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewHeader" />
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- CONTENT LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="40dip">
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <ScrollView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:background="#EEEEEE">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="50px"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:background="#EEEEEE">
                <TextView
                    android:text="MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText MediumText"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- FOOTER -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/footer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewFooter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks to help me :-)

Comment: Define the RelativeLayout to be below the LinearLayout to avoid overlapping. eg. Add `android:layout_below="@+id/content"` to the Footer RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `layout_below` and `layout_above`, to keep your content between header and footer (there's no need to manually set `paddingTop`).-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerr"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

By the way, you have a typo in your header id (`@+id/headerr`)

Comment: Beautifull @ssantos! and last detail, how can I extend the header and footer background to the maximum widht? there is 1mm on the right and on the left for the footer...

Comment: Mmh, a `fill_parent` value for `layoud_width` should be ok. I'm guessing the width of your footer image is less than the display. Remove `adjustViewBounds` and set width to `fill_parent` also for the `ImageView`

Comment: Okay. When I remove the adjustViewBounds in fact, there is a white space under the footer (the adjustviewbounds hide that hole but create two others haha ) So actually I have a hole under the footer

Comment: Well, that's a half of the holes, we're doing some progress here :) Not sure if that's the problem, but you don't need `android:layout_above="@id/footer"` either in your image.

Comment: It doesn't work.. I use android:scaleType="centerCrop" but it doesn't satisfy me

Comment: What about other `scaleTypes` such as `fitXY`?

Comment: It solved the problem for this resolution, and if I try with a tablet, the header and footer will be awful, isn't it?

Comment: Most probably. You will have to choose between `compatibility mode` or manually dealing with different screen resolutions/densities: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html